# Duplicate Background image UIWebview when Scrolling on Webview in IOS

Tags: ios, webview, background-image

I'm developing IOS application. It has a `webView` with set background image, I faced a problem when scrolling on `webView` it duplicate background image because I saw it has 2 background image. It look like one for `webView` and one more under it like background image for **view controller**.

Here my code for set background image in `viewDidLoad` :

```
webview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone4-screen.png"]];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean... is the background image being tiled? Could you try setting the webView to have a clear background, and putting a UIImageView behind it?

Comment: please make your ques understandable...I am not getting what is your ques.